# How to map an array inside an object inside table component?

Tags: reactjs

I have an object that contains an array, the array contains objects. I'v used map ofcourse but here nothing seem to work. my goal is to display all the lessons a student has.Meaning the object represents a student. the backend is comming from django python and my design that on specific url displays the student lessons.I olly want to use the lessons so the stuList variable isnt relevent at the moment.
thank you.
consol.log

````
    lessons {stuLessons: Array(3)}stuLessons: Array(3)0: {id: 35, student: "Sany", title: "Music", lesson_date: "2021-06-09", paid: "not paid", …}1: {id: 29, student: "Sany", title: "Math 581", lesson_date: "2021-06-03", paid: "paid", …}2: {id: 27, student: "Sany", title: "History", lesson_date: "2021-06-02", paid: "paid", …}length: 3__proto__: Array(0)__proto__: Object
    StudentLessons.js:37 type object
    ```
consol.log

    ```
    lessons {stuLessons: Array(3)}stuLessons: Array(3)
0: {id: 35, student: "Sany", title: "Music", lesson_date: "2021-06-09", paid: "not paid", …}
1: {id: 29, student: "Sany", title: "Math 581", lesson_date: "2021-06-03", paid: "paid", …}
2: {id: 27, student: "Sany", title: "History", lesson_date: "2021-06-02", paid: "paid", …}
length: 3__proto__: Array(0)__proto__: Object
    StudentLessons.js:37 type object
    ```

StudentLessons.js

    ``import React, { useEffect, useState} from "react";
    import axiosInstance from "./../axios";
    import Container from "@material-ui/core/Container";
    import Paper from "@material-ui/core/Paper";
    import Table from "@material-ui/core/Table";
    import TableBody from "@material-ui/core/TableBody";
    import TableCell from "@material-ui/core/TableCell";
    import TableContainer from "@material-ui/core/TableContainer";
    import TableRow from "@material-ui/core/TableRow";
    import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
    
    const useStyles = makeStyles((theme)=>({
      table: {
        minWidth: "450",
      }
    }));
    
    
    const StudentLessons = ({studentid})=>{
      const classes = useStyles();
      const [stuList,setStuList] = useState("");
      const [stuLessons,setStulessons]=useState("");
        useEffect (()=>{
          axiosInstance.get('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/student/'+studentid+'/').then((res)=>{
            setStuList({...stuList,stuList:res.data
                              ,studentName:res.data.first_name});
            setStulessons({...stuLessons,stuLessons:res.data.lessons});                  
            
          })
    
        },[])
    
    console.log('stuList',stuList);
    console.log('name',stuList.studentName);
    console.log('lessons',stuLessons);
    console.log('type',typeof(stuLessons));
           
     return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <Container>
       <Paper>
       <TableContainer component={Paper}>
         <Table className={classes?.table} aria-label="simple table">
         <TableBody>
           {/* { (stuLessons["lessons"]).map(([lessonx])=>( */}       
           <TableRow  >      
           <TableCell >
             {/* {lessonx[1]}  */}
            
           </TableCell>
           </TableRow>
             {/* ))}   */}
         </TableBody> 
         </Table> 
         </TableContainer>
       </Paper>
       </Container>
       </React.Fragment>
     );
    }
    
    export default  StudentLessons;`
    ```
````

Answer (score 0):

Ok, you have

```
const data = {stuLessons: [
   {id: 35, student: "Sany", title: "Music", lesson_date: "2021-06-09", paid: "not paid"},
   {id: 29, student: "Sany", title: "Math 581", lesson_date: "2021-06-03", paid: "paid"},
   {id: 27, student: "Sany", title: "History", lesson_date: "2021-06-02", paid: "paid"}
]};
```

what you can do is:

```
data[Object.keys(data)].map(info => {
  console.log(info.title)
})
```

should print

```
"Music"
"Math 581"
"History"
```

Comment: `Object.keys(data)` would just return `["stuLessons"]` in your example. It seems like you mean `data.stuLessons` instead? Or possibly `Object.values(data)`, but that would require another level of `map`.

Comment: @edemaine yes, you are correct saying that `Object.keys(data)` would just return "stuLessons"` ... and that's wht we do `data[Object.keys(data)].map(...)` which is basically the same as `data.stuLessons.map(...)` , but in my example is safer cause in the case `stuLessons` changes to another name, it wouldn't break the function. And also, if you do only `Object.values(data)` it will return the array with objects, not the values inside of it

Comment: Ah, I see. That does work if `data` has only one item. It won't work if there are multiple keys.  `data[Object.keys(data)[0]]` would be somewhat safer, but I guess we don't have a defined behavior for multiple keys, so it's not clear what's best.

Comment: thank you very much, but it didnt work, the object's name is not data

Comment: I tried to set it in  a const named data, but still didnt work.

Comment: @Anat your code above is a little confusing, if you could format it better it would be easier to understand. Anyways, you just need to change `data` to whatever you are calling it. Is it `stuLessons` ?

Comment: I tried to retrieve data from an object inside an array. So I converted the object to an array and was able to go through the data. Thank you very much for your help and time.